# Cannot open .xib file (com.apple.InterfaceBuilder error -1.)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface-builder, xib

I just upgraded to OS X YoSemite and suddenly my Xcode project cannot open one .xib file
It crashes with message:

```
The document "xxx.xib" could not be opened. The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.InterfaceBuilder error -1.)
```

My console log reads:

```
Xcode[3039]: Exception raised while unarchiving document objects - *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 9223372036854775807 beyond bounds for empty array
```

I have read other threads where there are issues around custom fonts. I do not believe that i have any custom fonts. i opened the xib file on another machine and went through the elements but cannot find custom fonts.

Comment: https://bugreport.apple.com